# GLSL precision qualifiers ignored

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, precision, fragment-shader

We have OpenGLES2.0 shaders that work fine on IOS and most Android devices but on the Amazon Kindle Fire 7 it seems that one of our varying components is losing precision

its defined in the vertex shader and pixel shader as

```
varying highp vec4 v_worldposition;
```

and we also have

```
precision highp float;
```

at the top of each file.

Yet, on this one device, the precision gets worse and worse the higher the numbers are. There's lots of accuracy around 0, but as the position gets to 200+ the precision drops to about 0.1 units - so it seems that the shader is using 16 bit floating point. In my mind, not highp at all, but maybe that's all it can do?

It's possible that it's using 16 bit floating point for all varying components but it shows up really badly in our case as we are texturing in the pixel shader based on world coordinates.

Does anyone know if there is a way to force 32 bit floating point in the shader or other code, or if the Amazon Fire 7 can even support it. Could it be a setting in the manifest? This is the only Android device we've seen this problem on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenGLES 2 spec allows devices to only support mediump precision in the fragment shader.

Presumably the Amazon Kindle Fire 7's Mali-450MP4 GPU is one such device. It is possible to query at runtime with `glGetShaderPrecisionFormat`.

You either have to drop support for such devices (easier said than done because there's no simple manifest option) or you have to refactor your shader so that you don't rely on high precision, or detect at runtime and use a lower detail shader for this sort of device. I tend to do the latter.

Comment: I guess it completely depends on what the "mediump" precision is then. We have changed the shader but we'll also check the precision as you suggest. Thanks.